# Modifying data file with certain condition in row

Tags: python, text, text-files

I have a question about modifying data with a reference file.

A reference file (def.dat) contains three rows and one column like

```
5
10
25
```

The data file (abc.dat) contains numbers and words like

```
1 3 4
2 4 5

Atoms

1 4 5
1 5 6
5 8 4   <--- Here
3 5 10
3 5 9
6 2 6
6 8 9
10 6 7   <---- Here
8 5 4
8 8 6
45 5 9
45 10 54
25 10 1   <---- Here

Velocities

1 3 4
3 5 7
```

I would like change the data file after comparing the reference file values.

For example, if reference values are 5, 10, and 25, I would like to change the value in third column in the data file only in Atoms section like,

```
1 3 4
2 4 5

Atoms

1 4 5
1 5 6
5 8 100  <--- Here
3 5 10
3 5 9
6 2 6
6 8 9
10 6 100 <--- Here
8 5 4
8 8 6
45 5 9
45 10 54
25 10 100 <--- Here

Velocities

1 3 4
3 5 7
```

I tried the following code but only the reference value 5 was changes like.

```
1 3 4
2 4 5

Atoms

1 4 5
1 5 6
5 8 100  <--- only Here
3 5 10
3 5 9
6 2 6
6 8 9
10 6 7
8 5 4
8 8 6
45 5 9
45 10 54
25 10 1

Velocities

1 3 4
3 5 7
```

===========================Code ================

```
with open('def', 'r') as f1, open('abc', 'r') as f2, open('out.txt', 'w') as f3:
    state = 1

    for line1 in f1:
            sp1 = line1.split()
            for line2 in f2:
                    sp2 = line2.split()
                    line2 = " ".join(sp2) + '\n'

                    if line2 in ['\n', '\r\n']:
                            line2 = " ".join(sp2) + '\n'

                    elif line2 == 'Atoms\n':
                            state = 2

                    elif line2 == 'Velocities\n':
                            state = 3

                    if state == 1:
                            line2 = " ".join(sp2) + '\n'

                    elif state == 2:
                            if line2 == 'Atoms\n':
                                    line2 = " ".join(sp2) +'\n'

                            elif line2 in ['\n', '\r\n']:
                                    line2 = " ".join(sp2) +'\n'

                            else:
                                    if sp2[0] == sp1:
                                            sp2[2] = '10'
                                            line2 = " ".join(sp2) + '\n'

                    else:
                            line2 = " ".join(sp2) + '\n'

                    f3.write(line2)
```

=========================================================

Any comments appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your code. See comment in the code.

```
with open('def') as f1, open('abc') as f2, open('out.txt', 'w') as f3:
    in_atoms = False # state -> in_atoms (only 2 states)

    # read `def` file content into memory as set
    references = set(f1.read().split())

    # Removed a loop which iterate reference file.
    for line in f2:
        if line.startswith('Atoms'):
            in_atoms = True
        elif line.startswith('Velocities'):
            in_atoms = False
        elif in_atoms:
            values = line.split()
            # Check number match with one of the references.
            if values and values[0] in references:
                values[2] = '100'
                line = ' '.join(values) + '\n'
        f3.write(line)
```

Comment: Thank you for the valuable comments and code modified. It helps a lot. Is, however, the second "references." in the last if statement a mistake?

Comment: @ChangWoonJang, Yes it was mistake. I fixed it.